# How to terminate anonymous threads in Delphi on application close?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2, anonymous, terminate

I have a Delphi application which spawns 6 anonymous threads upon some TTimer.OnTimer event.

If I close the application from the X button in titlebar Access Violation at address $C0000005 is raised and FastMM reports leaked TAnonymousThread objects.

Which is the best way to free anonymous threads in Delphi created within OnTimer event with TThread.CreateAnonymousThread() method?

SOLUTION which worked for me:

Created a wrapper of the anonymous threads which terminates them upon being Free-ed.

```
type
  TAnonumousThreadPool = class sealed(TObject)
  strict private
    FThreadList: TThreadList;
    procedure TerminateRunningThreads;
    procedure AnonumousThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    destructor Destroy; override; final;
    procedure Start(const Procs: array of TProc);
  end;

{ TAnonumousThreadPool }

procedure TAnonumousThreadPool.Start(const Procs: array of TProc);
var
  T: TThread;
  n: Integer;
begin
  TerminateRunningThreads;

  FThreadList := TThreadList.Create;
  FThreadList.Duplicates := TDuplicates.dupError;

  for n := Low(Procs) to High(Procs) do
  begin
    T := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(Procs[n]);
    TThread.NameThreadForDebugging(AnsiString('Test thread N:' + IntToStr(n) + ' TID:'), T.ThreadID);
    T.OnTerminate := AnonumousThreadTerminate;
    T.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    FThreadList.LockList;
    try
      FThreadList.Add(T);
    finally
      FThreadList.UnlockList;
    end;
    T.Start;
  end;
end;

procedure TAnonumousThreadPool.AnonumousThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FThreadList.LockList;
  try
    FThreadList.Remove((Sender as TThread));
  finally
    FThreadList.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TAnonumousThreadPool.TerminateRunningThreads;
var
  L: TList;
  T: TThread;
begin
  if not Assigned(FThreadList) then
    Exit;
  L := FThreadList.LockList;
  try
    while L.Count > 0 do
    begin
      T := TThread(L[0]);
      T.OnTerminate := nil;
      L.Remove(L[0]);
      T.FreeOnTerminate := False;
      T.Terminate;
      T.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FThreadList.UnlockList;
  end;
  FThreadList.Free;
end;

destructor TAnonumousThreadPool.Destroy;
begin
  TerminateRunningThreads;
  inherited;
end;
```

End here is how you can call it:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FAnonymousThreadPool.Start([ // array of procedures to execute
    procedure{anonymous1}()
    var
      Http: THttpClient;
    begin
      Http := THttpClient.Create;
      try
        Http.CancelledCallback := function: Boolean
          begin
            Result := TThread.CurrentThread.CheckTerminated;
          end;
        Http.GetFile('http://mtgstudio.com/Screenshots/shot1.png', 'c:\1.jpg');
      finally
        Http.Free;
      end;
    end,

    procedure{anonymous2}()
    var
      Http: THttpClient;
    begin
      Http := THttpClient.Create;
      try
        Http.CancelledCallback := function: Boolean
          begin
            Result := TThread.CurrentThread.CheckTerminated;
          end;
        Http.GetFile('http://mtgstudio.com/Screenshots/shot2.png', 'c:\2.jpg');
      finally
        Http.Free;
      end;
    end
  ]);
end;
```

No memory leaks, proper shutdown and easy to use.

Comment: 'anonymous threads' - Oh great.. what have Embarcadero foisted on us now?

Comment: @Martin: Nothing scary, really. It's a thread whose behavior is provided at creation time by an anonymous method.  It lets you use closures when defining threads.

Comment: It's continually create/destroy threads, something I've spent the last 20 years telling developers to avoid.  Nevertheless, if not actually started, I can't see why there should be an AV.

Comment: Gad, I'm sure that's not the *address* of the access violation; $C0000005 is the Windows exception code for access violations. Please copy and paste the actual error-message text. (You can press Ctrl+C in the dialog box to copy the entire dialog's text.)

Comment: What's stopping you from using the debugger to find the location of the access violation? If you can't, maybe someone else can; post minimal code necessary for reproducing the error. (It's best if you can reproduce it by starting with a new, blank application.)

Comment: Hmm.. having read the documentation, (I have D2009 - no anonymous threads.  I have to say that, so far, the tears are not exactly pouring down my cheeks), then some of these threads probably are running because Valgrind reports their objects still there.

Comment: Your "solution" is puzzling. First, you call `WaitFor`, and then call `Terminate`. `WaitFor` won't return until the thread has stopped, so once that's happened, why tell the thread it's time to stop? Also, this code leaks memory: if the thread terminates naturally, it removes itself from the list without getting destroyed, and the thread you wait for isn't necessarily the same one you remove. Finally, you have a race condition that can lead to out-of-bounds exceptions or further memory leaks. Simplify: Don't set `OnTerminate` at all, and in `OnDestroy`, do this: `for T in L do T.Free`.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Your comments on memory leak and meaningless WaitFor() leaned me to the TAnonymousThreadPool solutuion.

Comment: Further issues in the new code: Instead of leaking, threads that terminate by themselves can get double-freed. Since the anonymous method has no reference to the thread object, it cannot check the `Terminated` property, so calling `Terminate` does nothing. (Calling `Free` would call `Terminate` anyway.) There's no reason for a thread-safe list since it's only ever accessed in a single thread. Have you considered using [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? It provides more room to talk about code than these comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to maintain and exert control over a thread's lifetimes then it must have `FreeOnTerminate` set to `False`. Otherwise it is an error to refer to the thread after it has started executing. That's because once it starts executing, you've no ready way to know whether or not it has been freed.

The call to [`CreateAnonymousThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) creates a thread with `FreeOnTerminate` set to `True`.

> The thread is also marked as FreeOnTerminate, so you should not touch the returned instance after calling Start.

And so, but default, you are in no position to exert control over the thread's lifetime. However, you could set `FreeOnTerminate` to `False` immediately before calling `Start`. Like this:

```
MyThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(MyProc);
MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := False;
MyThread.Start;
```

However, I'm not sure I would do that. The design of `CreateAnonymousThread` is that the thread is automatically freed upon termination. I think I personally would either follow the intended design, or derive my own `TThread` descendent.

Comment: I see. But I still do not get it. TAnonymousThread is a descendant of TThread. So I can maintain a list of them and try to terminate them (since the RTL does not do it automatically). When I try to terminate it says: Project mtgstudio.exe raised exception class EThread with message 'Thread Error: The handle is invalid (6)'.

Comment: Read the docs for the anonymous thread. You are not allowed to hold a reference to the TThread since it uses FreeOnTerminate.

Comment: Sorry, I can't look at this project. I think I answered the question you asked. Essentially, one you start an anonymous thread you lose control over it. You can no longer reference it.

Comment: The docs mentioned are: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread

Comment: You can control anonymous threads as it is an normal TThread it i just initialized as FreeOnTerminate ... as I've posted in my answear. So you should edit your answear and remove the part that says "you should not use anonymous threads"

Answer (score 9):

To avoid errors using `CreateAnonymousThread` just set `FreeOnTerminate` to `False` before starting it.

This way you can work with the thread as you usually do without any workaround.

You can read the documentation that says that `CreateAnonymousThread` automatically sets `FreeOnTerminate` to `True` and this is what is causing the errors when you reference the thread.

Answer (score 3):

Make your threads watch for some kind of notification from the outside. This could be an event that gets signaled, a message sent to a window owned by the thread, a command sent over a socket that your thread listens to, or whatever other form of communication you find.

If you determine that this problem is because your threads are so-called "anonymous" threads, then a simple workaround is for you to make them be non-anonymous threads. Put the body of the anonymous function into the `Execute` method, and pass any captured variables to the thread class via its constructor.

Comment: You can easily enough pass an anonymous method to a TThread descendent and execute that in the Execute method.

Comment: Of course, @David. Isn't `CreateAnonymousThread` proof of that? So what?

Comment: I mean that it would be an alternative to the approach suggested in the final sentence of your answer.